# mysql command line return execution time?

Tags: mysql, profiling

I'm working on a Linux host with mysql command. I have a script that runs batch mysql commands (like `mysql -e "select..."`) and I wish to summarize execution time of each of the commands.

Is there a way to get mysql exec time from the command line?

For example, in mysql interactive mode, execution result comes with a time, like this:

```
mysql> select count(*) from trialtable;
+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|     4000 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Can I get the same profile in command line?

Thank you

Comment: Is it fair game to throw `time` in front of the commands? Or do you want the _real_ amount of execution time that MySQL consumes while computing the results?

Comment: @sarnold Yes I wish to see "real" time.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can use

```
set profiling=1
```

and then, later,

```
show profiles
```

which will give a list of commands and times.

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-profiles.html

h/t http://ronaldbradford.com/blog/timing-your-sql-queries-2010-07-07/

Answer (score 16):

You can invoke mysql with `-vv`, it will pretty-print similar to when you're in interactive mode:

```
$ mysql -vv -u myUser -pMyPass DBname -e 'select count(*) from mytable;'
--------------
select count(*) from mytable
--------------

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  1068316 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

Bye
```

If you're piping your queries, then it's `-vvv`:

```
$ echo 'select count(*) from mytable;' | mysql -vvv -u myUser -pMyPass DBname
--------------
select count(*) from mytable
--------------

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|  1068316 |
+----------+
1 row in set (1.34 sec)

Bye
```

Time's yours to grep. :D

Comment: This answer is particularly good when using the mysql client with ClickHouse, which supports the mysql tcp wire format.  The reason being that `set profiling=1` (as suggested in the accepted answer) does not work on ClickHouse.  To be fair, the original question was about using the client with a MySQL server and not with a different DB server that happens to be mysql line wire compatible.  However, for anyone looking to use the mysql client with ClickHouse or possibly other DB's that are mysql line wire compatible, this is the best bet.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the exact syntax for PHP.

```
mysql_query("SET profiling = 1;");
if (mysql_errno()) { die( "ERROR ".mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) ); }

$query="SELECT some_field_name FROM some_table_name";
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (mysql_errno()) { die( "ERROR ".mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) ); }

$exec_time_result=mysql_query("SELECT query_id, SUM(duration) FROM information_schema.profiling GROUP BY query_id ORDER BY query_id DESC LIMIT 1;");
if (mysql_errno()) { die( "ERROR ".mysql_errno($link) . ": " . mysql_error($link) ); }
$exec_time_row = mysql_fetch_array($exec_time_result);

echo "<p>Query executed in ".$exec_time_row[1].' seconds';
```