# Reporting time for each query in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am learning MySQL and stuck on this step where I want to show/see as an output the response/report service time of each query.

I searched for similar requests but all I could understand is the one with "show profiles" query and since it's not working, Can I ask for another alternative?

I just want to report the service time of each query in MySQL [and get it explicitly just after running the queries in the terminal]? You can call it a response time as well.

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43946899/5962802

Comment: Look for general log and slow log